# X screen rotation with DSI port

Tags: display, touchscreen, xorg, pi-3a+, dsi

I've been having the worst time trying to get the official rpi 7" touch to rotate consistently.  I'm using openbox.  I am able to manipulate the touch orientation using config.txt, but changing lines in cmdline.txt doesn't seem to net any results in X.  It does *SOMETIMES* rotate the terminal display, but once in X it's different.

Here's my cmdline.txt:

`console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=83fea24d-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait video=DSI-1:800x480@60,rotate=90`

Here's my (relevant) config.txt:

```
display_auto_detect=1
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2
disable_overscan=1
gpu_mem=128
```

Here's my autostart:

```
xrandr --output DSI-1 --auto --rotate right--verbose &
xscreensaver -no-splash &
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences &
sed -i 's/"exit_type": "Crashed"/"exit_type": "Normal"/' ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences &
chromium-browser --noerrors --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars --start-maximized --app=http://127.0.0.1:5000/?#tab_plugin_resource_monitor &
```

What I am looking for is reliable permanent screen rotation.  What else do I need to do to fix this?  The [raspberry pi documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/display.html) doesn't cut it and much of the documentation\discussion I do find is old or also doesn't work out.

Update(s): The current settings shown above work if I slowly and methodically enter X.  If I let the pi auto login to X, the orientation fails or at best is extremely inconsistent.  Also, I have 3 identical setups.  Pi3a+, Rpi Touch 7", 5A Power supply.  None of the three behave the same even with identical settings.  I'm trying to work on one at a time and just clone the SD card but last time I tried that it also didnt work.  One of the three wouldn't rotate.

```
addohm@mk4-octopi:~ $ uname -a
Linux mk4-octopi 6.1.21-v7+ #1642 SMP Mon Apr  3 17:20:52 BST 2023 armv7l GNU/Linux
addohm@mk4-octopi:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

Comment: @Milliways thanks, added the relevant info.